# In Django ModelAdmin, how to allow editing of ForeignKey objects but not reassignment?

Tags: django

I work with structure which can be simplified like this:

```
# models.py
class Order(models.Model):
    payment = models.ForeignKey('Payment', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # other fields

class Payment(models.Model):
    # fields

# admin.py
@admin.register(Payment)
class PaymentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Payment
    fields = (...)
    readonly_fields = (...)

    def get_model_perms(self, request):
        return {}

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Order
    fields = ('payment', ...)
```

now, what I want to do is to allow the `Payment` object to be edited from popup in `OrderAdmin` by clicking the pencil icon. However, I don't want to allow the admin to reassign it (to change linked payment from `PaymentObject(1)` to `PaymentObject(2)` or to `null` for example). Because I want to be able to edit the `payment`, I can't mark the `payment` field as read only.

I can't change the `ForeignKey` relation, because that would require huge refactor. I would prefer a solution that only deals with forms, but even a hacky one is better than nothing I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. It's not exactly what I had in mind, but it does the job: I rendered the `payment` field as a link to payment admin:

```
 @admin.register(Order)
 class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     model = Order
     fields = ('display_payment', ...)
     read_only_fields = ['display_payment']

    def display_payment(self, obj):
        payment_url = reverse('admin:appname_payment_change', args=(obj.payment.id,))
         return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', payment_url, str(obj.payment))
    display_payment.short_description = 'Payment'
```

Answer (score 0):

https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/changeview_readonly.html

Try this out

```
@admin.register(Hero)
class HeroAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
    ...
    readonly_fields = ["father", "mother", "spouse"]
```